# Celery worker does not consume messages

Tags: django, celery

I'm using Celery 4.0.0 with RabbitMQ as messages broker within a django 1.9 project, using django-celery-results for results backend. I'm new to Celery and RabbitMQ. The python version is 2.7.5.

After following the instructions in the Celery docs for configuring and using celery with django, and before adding any real tasks, I tried a simple task calling using django shell (manage.py shell), sending the debug_task as defined in the celery docs.

Task is sent OK, and looking at the rabbitmq queue, I can see a new message has arrived to the correct queue on the correct virtual host.
I run the worker and it looks like it starts OK, then it arrives to the event loop and does nothing. No error is presented, not in the worker output or in the rabbitmq logs.

On the other hand, celery status on the same machine returns that there are no active nodes.

I'm probably missing something here, but I don't know what it can be.

Don't know if this is relevant, but when I use 'celery purge' to clear the messages queue, it finds the message and purges it.

Celery configuration settings as added to django settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user1:passwd1@rabbithost:5672/exp'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE    # Using django's TZ
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

Task invocation in django shell:

```
>>> from project.celery import debug_task
>>> debug_task
<@task: project.celery.debug_task of project:0x23cad10>
>>> r = debug_task.delay()
>>> r
<AsyncResult: 33031998-4cd8-4dfe-8e9d-bda9398525bb>
>>> r.status
u'PENDING'
```

Celery worker invocation:

```
% celery -A project worker -l info -Q celery

 -------------- celery@super9 v4.0.0 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.2.1511-Core 2016-11-24 18:15:27
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         project:0x25931d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://user1:**@rabbithost:5672/exp
- ** ---------- .> results:     
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 24 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . project.celery.debug_task

[2016-11-24 18:15:28,984: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://user1:**@rabbithost:5672/exp
[2016-11-24 18:15:29,009: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-11-24 18:15:30,035: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
/dir/project/devel/python/devel-1.9-centos7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2016-11-24 18:15:30,072: WARNING/MainProcess] /dir/project/devel/python/devel-1.9-centos7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2016-11-24 18:15:30,073: INFO/MainProcess] celery@super9 ready.
```

Checking rabbitmq queue:

```
% rabbitmqctl list_queues -p exp
Listing queues ...
celery  1
```

Celery status invocation while the worker is "ready":

```
% celery -A project status
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `librabbitmq` installed ?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Comment: Try uninstalling `librabbitmq` and restart worker again. Tasks get processed. I faced this behaviour.

Comment: I uninstalled `librabbitmq`. Still the same. The celery worker just stays idle. And `celery purge` is able to find the messages and purge them.

Comment: And `celery -A project status` claims it cannot find active nodes, while the worker is running and is "ready".

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I am in the same position right now.